# Alternative for RealVNC?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I'm searching for a free alternative of RealVNC for Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11).

I have one "special need" for the program. I need to be able to change the port of the Mac I am currently using.

I couldn't find anything yet, at least nothing that works with El Capitan... 
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Chicken

If you are looking for a VNC client, the open source [Chicken](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/) client supports connecting to specific ports.

### Tiger VNC

You can install [Tiger VNC](http://tigervnc.org) via the [brew](https://brew.sh) project with:

```
brew install tiger-vnc
```

### macOS Built-in Screen Sharing

Alternatively, you can use macOS's built in **Screen Sharing** application to connect to specific ports via a well formed URL, such as `vnc://192.168.1.34:5901`.

## VNC Servers

For VNC servers, other than the [built-in macOS VNC server](http://dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc/), take a look at [OSXvnc](https://github.com/stweil/OSXvnc).

### Tunneling

You could take a different approach and [tunnel the existing VNC service](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html) through `ssh` or another tool. This would expose the VNC service through any port you desire without needing a special VNC server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the port number for the built-in screen sharing URL.  That was the part I was missing when trying to connect to a Linux box running a TightVNC server.

Comment: OSXvnc only gives me like 8 fps and only one display at a time.